# How to make custom implementation of Retrofit2.Call<T>

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2 and I want to Override its Call.enqueue method.

I did this so far:

**Custom Call:**

```
    public class CustomCall<T> implements Call<T> {

        private final Call<T> delegate;
        //..every method has delegate method invoked in it
```

**Apis:**

```
        @GET
        CustomCall<TKBaseResponse> testConnection(@Url String customUrl);
```

But I keep getting these errors:

```
    Unable to create call adapter for CustomCall<....>
```

and

```
    Could not locate call adapter for CustomCall<....>
```

Any way on how can I do this properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can start by showing the rest of the Call code, and the complete error logs

Comment: why u need to create CustomCall? just create any interface class that contain simple Call with <your own object> should be sufficient to create any application that connect to any webservice, isn't it?

Comment: Please take a look from here https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/sampleapp/api

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First create a ServiceManager class -

```
public final class ServiceManager {

    private static ServiceManager sServiceManager;

    /**
     * Gets the instance of the web services implementation.
     *
     * @return the singleton instance.
     */
    public static ServiceManager get() {
        if (sServiceManager == null) {
            sServiceManager = new ServiceManager();
        }
        return sServiceManager;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the services for a given HTTP Url, useful when testing
     * through multiple endpoints and unit testing
     *
     * @param clazz the service class.
     * @param <T>   type of the service.
     * @return the created services implementation.
     */
    public <T> T createService(Class<T> clazz) {
        return createService(clazz, HttpUrl.parse(ServiceApiEndpoints.SERVICE_ENDPOINT));
    }

    /**
     * Creates the services for a given HTTP Url, useful when testing
     * through multiple endpoints and unit testing
     *
     * @param clazz   the service class.
     * @param httpUrl the endpoint
     * @param <T>     type of the service.
     * @return the created services implementation.
     */
    public <T> T createService(Class<T> clazz, HttpUrl httpUrl) {
        Retrofit retrofit = getRetrofit(httpUrl);
        return retrofit.create(clazz);
    }

    public <T> T createService(Class<T> clazz, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(clazz);
    }

    private Retrofit getRetrofit(HttpUrl httpUrl) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(httpUrl)
                .client(createClient())
                .addConverterFactory(getConverter())
                .build();
    }

    public Retrofit getPlainRetrofit(HttpUrl httpUrl) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(httpUrl)
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
                .addConverterFactory(getConverter())
                .build();
    }

    private Converter.Factory getConverter() {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create();
    }


    private OkHttpClient createClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor()).build();
    }

}
```

ServiceApiEndpoints is a class contains service endpoints.

```
final class ServiceApiEndpoints {

    public static final String SERVICE_ENDPOINT = "your_app_url";
}
```

Create an interface APIService

```
public interface APIService {
 String GET_INFO = "get_info";

    @GET(GET_INFO)
    Call<ResInfo[]> getInfo();
}
```

Create ResInfo model.

```
public class ResInfo {
    private static final String FIELD_CONTENT = "content";

    public String getContent() {
        return mContent;
    }

    public void setContent(final String content) {
        mContent = content;
    }


    @SerializedName(FIELD_CONTENT)
    private String mContent;

    public ResInfo(){

    }
}
```

Call the request.

```
    private Call<ResInfo[]> mGetInfoAPICall;

    APIService apiService=ServiceManager.get().createService(APIService.class);
    mGetInfoAPICall = apiService.getInfo();
    mGetInfoAPICall.enqueue(new Callback<ResInfo[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResInfo[]> call, Response<ResInfo[]> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResInfo[]> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting below an example to help you with retrofit implementation.

Create your resource like this (MyResource.java).

```
Call<TKBaseResponse> testConnection(@@Url String customUrl);
```

Initialize Retrofit

```
private Resource getRetrofitResource(){
   //Initialize retrofit.
   final Retrofit = .....//your code to initialize retrofit
   return retrofit.create(MyResource.class);
}
```

To implement call enqueue(async retrofit calls) you need to pass your resource response and a response handler which is your custom implementation into the enqueue method. I am posting my implementation of ResponseHandler alongside.

```
public abstract class ResponseHandler<T> {

    private static final String TAG = ResponseHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    private final Context context;

    public ResponseHandler() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ResponseHandler(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public abstract void onResponse(final T response);

    public void onError(final ErrorResponse errorResponse) {
        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred while invoking service. Error Code: " + errorResponse.getErrorCode() + LINE_SEPARATOR + "Message: " + errorResponse.getMessage() + LINE_SEPARATOR);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setTitle(R.string.title_server_error_dialog);
        alertBuilder.setMessage(R.string.network_error_message);
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.text_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertBuilder.show();
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        if (context == null) {
            return;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred while invoking service", throwable);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setTitle(R.string.title_network_error_dialog);
        alertBuilder.setMessage(R.string.network_error_message);
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.text_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertBuilder.show();
    }

}
```

Create a method handle response.

```
protected <T> void handleResponse(Call<T> call, final ResponseHandler<T> responseHandler) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final Call<T> call, final Response<T> response) {
               if (response.isSuccess()) {
                if (responseHandler != null ) {
                    responseHandler.onResponse(response.body());
                }
            } else {
                final ErrorResponse errorResponse = parseError(response);
                if (responseHandler != null) {
                    responseHandler.onError(errorResponse);
                }
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Call<T> call, final Throwable throwable) {
               if (responseHandler != null) {
                responseHandler.onFailure(throwable);
            }
            }
        });
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any doubts around this.

Now from call your resource like below.

```
final MyResource resource = getRetrofitResource();
final Call<TKBaseResponse> response = resource .testConnection("ANY_URL_OF_YOUR_CHOICE");
handleResponse(response, new ResponseHandler<TKBaseResponse>(){

 public void onResponse(final TKBaseResponse response){
      //Do whatever you want to do here..
 }
    });
```

Comment: From what library is **Resource**?

Comment: MyResource is nothing but a simple java interface. you can follow the below link for more indepth. 

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

I will try to pull out some time and prepare a git project for you to demonstrate a very basic usage with proper code structure.
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer my question on how I can Override the enqueue function of Call<T>

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know if you have further doubts with enqueue function implementation